# Retrieving chromebook user email in extension

Tags: email, google-chrome-extension, chromebook

I have a chrome extension installed on a Chromebook. I'm looking for a way for that extension to retrieve the email address with which I'm currently signed into the Chromebook. I tried using the following:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo){
    console.log(userInfo.email);
});
```

However it's always empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25547737/3889449), to use the new `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo` API you'll need to request the permission for `"identity.email"` in your manifest.

So first of all add it to your `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": {
    ...
    "identity.email"
    ...
}
```

Then you can call the method as you wanted:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(info) {
    console.log(info);
});

// {email: "someone@somesite.com", id: xxxxxx}
```

Comment: Thank you! I only had "identity" in permissions, that's why it wasn't working.